# SVG reduced path with fill pattern

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I try to draw a shape with a path that must be reduced like in this solution [Find Parallel or Offset SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411999/find-parallel-or-offset-svg-path)
I use the filter "erode" but with pattern it doesn't work : the pattern is deformed.

Is there a way to do this without the bezier.js solution, with pure SVG/CSS ?

Here is a sample of my problem
I want to have the shape of the right with the pattern of the left.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <defs>
                <pattern id="circ" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <rect fill="blue" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green" />
                </pattern>
                <filter id="erode">
                    <feMorphology in="SourceGraphic" operator="erode" radius="10"/>
                </filter>
                <path id="thing" d="M 0,0 H 50 A 35,35 0 1 0 100,50 V 75 C 50,125 0,85 0,85 Z" />
            </defs>
            <use href="#thing" fill="url(#circ)" width="400" height="400" filter="#erode"/>
            <use x="100" href="#thing" filter="url(#erode)" fill="url(#circ)" width="400" height="400" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends on the pattern you are using. For many patterns, it's possible to still use a filter alone with the use of some more primitives. Please post the code of the SVG you want to do this to.

Comment: I edited my question with a snippet to illustrate my question. Thank you @MichaelMullany

Comment: I think it is a feature of this filter (rastered reduction)

Comment: Figured out how to work around browser bugs ... posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a mask.

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
}

.purple {
  fill: rebeccapurple;
}

.reduce-me {
  mask: url(#reducer);
}

#reduce-amount {
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="purple"
        d="M 50,10 Q 100,10, 50,50 Q 0,90, 50,90 
           Q 100,90, 50,50 Q 0,10, 50,10 Z"/>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <!-- the shared path that is used by both the purple path and the mask -->
    <path id="shared-path"
          id="p" d="M 50,10 Q 100,10, 50,50 Q 0,90, 50,90
                    Q 100,90, 50,50 Q 0,10, 50,10 Z" />

    <!-- a mask that shrinks the shape by half the stroke-width -->
    <mask id="reducer">
      <use id="reduce-amount" xlink:href="#shared-path"
           fill="white" stroke="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!-- the shape that gets reduced -->
  <use class="purple reduce-me" xlink:href="#shared-path"/>
</svg>
```

**How this works**

If we just render what the mask looks like (on the right) we can see how this works.

```css
svg {
  width: 300px;
}

.purple {
  fill: rebeccapurple;
}

.reduce-me {
  mask: url(#reducer);
}

#reduce-amount {
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="purple"
        d="M 50,10 Q 100,10, 50,50 Q 0,90, 50,90 
           Q 100,90, 50,50 Q 0,10, 50,10 Z"/>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <!-- the shared path that is used by both the purple path and the mask -->
    <path id="shared-path"
          id="p" d="M 50,10 Q 100,10, 50,50 Q 0,90, 50,90
                    Q 100,90, 50,50 Q 0,10, 50,10 Z" />
  </defs>

  <use id="reduce-amount" xlink:href="#shared-path"
       fill="white" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

We are using the same shape as a mask.  However the mask has a thick black stroke around it.  Black in a mask makes things transparent.  The rest of the mask is white, which stays visible.

You can alter the amount of the shape reduction by changing the `stroke-width` value in the `.reduce-amount` class.

The disadvantages of this method are:
1. you need a mask for every different path shape
2. you can't set the stroke style of the reduced size shape.  However you could simulate a stroke colour by overlaying two paths with different reduction amounts.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the filter to make this work. There seems to be a bug eroding pattern filled shapes - it's not taking the minimum of the alpha channels in the radius correctly. But if you start with SourceAlpha rather than SourceGraphic and then create your mask using component transfers it seems to work.

```html
           <svg>
            <defs>
                <pattern id="circ" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <rect fill="blue" width="100%" height="100%" />
                    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green" />
                </pattern>
              <filter id="erode3">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="eroded"
operator="erode" radius="10"/>
             <feComponentTransfer>
               <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="1 0"/>
               <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="1 0"/>
               <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="1 0"/>
              </feComponentTransfer>
            <feComposite operator ="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>

                <path id="thing" d="M 0,0 H 50 A 35,35 0 1 0 100,50 V 75 C 50,125 0,85 0,85 Z" />
            </defs>
            <use href="#thing" fill="url(#circ)" width="400" height="400" filter="url(#erode3)"/>
            <use x="100" href="#thing" filter="url(#erode)" fill="url(#circ)" width="400" height="400" />
        </svg>
```